# How should I adapt recipes according to the amount of sourdough starter?

Tags: sourdough

I use the starter irregularly, therefore the amount I take to make the dough changes every time: I work by taking a fixed amount of starter to feed further, and by using all the rest in the recipe.

However, even if the starter is fed with 100% hydration, the flour is consumed by the process: inevitably I won't have a 100% hydrated starter when I use it.

Last time I adapted the recipe (flour and water) by assuming 50% water and 50% flour in the starter, but I found out water was underestimated.

How should I adapt the recipes? or, what is the % of hydration in a starter, depending on its age since the last feeding?

Comment: Why would be there a difference? What feeding schedule are you using? Most schedules keep a constant ratio of water to flour.

Comment: Because yeast lives by eating sugars, broken down from the starch (hydrocarbons) of the flour and converting it into alcohol and CO2. Once the starter is lively and full of yeast, this process may not be negligible, I guess